# How to rotate a UAV system

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

Hello i want to rotate a UAV system by preserving the formation, is any simple way or maths formul to solve this problem.
[here is my UAVs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9tbu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the middle UAV as the centre and other UAV as points over the circumference.

Now using formulas in : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384994/rotate-a-point-on-a-circle-with-known-radius-and-position

You find the relative shift for each UAV.